# Testcontainers on Mac m1 could not create/start container

Tags: java, docker, arm, apple-m1, testcontainers

I am trying to use Testcontainers (1.17.6) to create GenericContainer on Mac m1 but get error:

`com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Status 500: {"message":"error while creating mount source path '/Users/k/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.raw.sock': mkdir /Users/k/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.raw.sock: operation not supported"}`

Docker version:

```
 Cloud integration: v1.0.29
 Version:           20.10.21
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.7
 Git commit:        baeda1f
 Built:             Tue Oct 25 18:01:18 2022
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.21
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.7
  Git commit:       3056208
  Built:            Tue Oct 25 17:59:41 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.10
  GitCommit:        770bd0108c32f3fb5c73ae1264f7e503fe7b2661
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Maven settings:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

What should I do to make it work?

I tried yet:

- that directories is exists

```
k@m ~ % ls -la /Users/k/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.raw.sock
srwxr-xr-x@ 1 k  staff  0 Apr  2 23:54 /Users/k/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.raw.sock
```

- disable properties check in testcontainers properties file (in log I see that custom properties file is seen and applied)

```
k@mbp ~ % cat .testcontainers.properties 
checks.disable=true
```

```
00:02:21.835 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.utility.TestcontainersConfiguration - Testcontainers configuration overrides will be loaded from file:/Users/k/.testcontainers.properties
```

- restart docker
- run PostgreSQL container, but have same error

Comment: It is unclear how you execute your Testcontainers test. Where does `docker.raw.sock` come from? Do you specify it anywhere?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I tried to exec it in terminal (mvn test) and IDEA (run test).
Both runs have same result

Comment: I do not specify docker.raw.sock anywhere

Comment: Did you try this reproducer project, same error? https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java-repro

Comment: Are you specifying `DOCKER_HOST`, `TESTCONTAINERS_SOCKET_OVERRIDE` or something similar as environment variables or in your `~/.testcontainers.properties` file?

Comment: DOCKER_HOST has been specified, removing helps, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As [Kevin Wittek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396362/kevin-wittek) says, I have DOCKER_HOST specified, removing that from envs helps.